# Csproj: Inherit Nugets from somwhere?

Tags: .net, csproj

I have a solution with many projects and test projects. While the References for the real projects vary wildly, the test project have mostly the same, maybe sometimes extra dependencies but nevers less - simply because we need the nuget references to enable running in our CI.

Adding (and maintaining) these refs to the dozens of unit tests projects is annoying. Is there a way to inherit these refs? So that TestProjectA and TestProjectB have the same Nugets?